# Class Names in same order produce different result(Chrome, Webpack 3, CSS modules)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am really sorry I can't produce the same behavior in CodePen.

I only have screenshots and codes, here they are:

Button in page 1

```html
<button class="Button__big___1_wGL Button__primary-inverse____49cG Button__button___Qt92K Button__button___1bkj2" type="button">
  <span>確定</span>
</button>
```

Button in page 2

```html
<button class="Button__big___1_wGL Button__primary-inverse____49cG Button__button___Qt92K Button__button___1bkj2" type="button">
  發送密碼重設信
</button>
```

Class Names are all the same:

```
Button__big___1_wGL Button__primary-inverse____49cG Button__button___Qt92K Button__button___1bkj2
```

But here is the difference

[image]

I am using CSS modules, Webpack 3, React and Google Chrome.

I can't reproduce the problem because my local dev setting is really complex.

Is it possible that in CSS world, exactly the same order class name produce a different result?

Comment: Does the order of the stylesheets change, class name order shouldn't matter

Comment: @LiefdeWen Do you mean that if I am using some kind of css-in-js, the final result is based on the dynamic stylesheet changing, not the order? Am I correct?

Comment: Chrome Inspector/ Developer Tools usually has a 'Computed' tab right next to 'Styles'. There you can see which line of CSS is responsible for the final computed value. From there, you can figure out which styles are overwritten because of precedence or specificity issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible that in CSS world, exactly the same order class name
>   produce a different result?

Order of classes is not important.  The order of stylesheets is important. E.g., you have the  same class `.foo { color: green }` in `styles.css` and `.foo { color: orange }` `main.css`

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and HTML:

```
<p class="foo">Footest</p>
```

Then color of text will be orange.
As browser loads and applies last loaded stylesheet(`<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`).